# How to refresh View after entering applicationWillEnterForeground?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell when controller has resumed from background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535907/how-to-tell-when-controller-has-resumed-from-background)

How to refresh View after user enters applicationWillEnterForeground?

I want to complete recall for example HomeViewController.

I have and update function in HomeViewController and I want when user enters to call update function and reload table data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any class can register to `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`, and react accordingly. It's not reserved to the app delegate, and helps for better separation of source code.

Comment: Have you some example link because I never user UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535907/how-to-tell-when-controller-has-resumed-from-background

Comment: Don't forget to remove the observer on dealloc!

Comment: C'mon, just look at the reference for `NSNotificationCenter`... it has some `removeObserver:` methods.

Comment: Problem, its not realoding table. - (void)enteredForeground:(NSNotification*) not
{
    
    [self.homeTableView reloadData];
}

Answer (score 9):

Create a viewDidLoad method like this for your HomeViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(yourUpdateMethodGoesHere:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

// Don't forget to remove the observer in your dealloc method. 
// Otherwise it will stay retained by the [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]...
- (void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

If your ViewController is a tableViewController your could also directly call the reload data function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[self tableView]
                                             selector:@selector(reloadData)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];

}
- (void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Or you could use a block:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                  [[self tableView] reloadData];
                                              }];
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the observer on dealloc!

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a property in your app delegate class that would point to the HomeViewController object. Then you can call your update function in applicationWillEnterForeground.