# I'd like to call when enter foreground in iOS

Tags: ios, foreground

I have only a `GalleryViewController` as `UIViewController`.
it's loaded by storyboard.

I'd like to call a method of my `GalleryViewController` in `AppDelegate.m`.
But I don't have reference of my `GalleryViewController` in `AppDelegate.m`.

Comment: Your `GalleryViewController` is you first `UIViewController` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell when controller has resumed from background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535907/how-to-tell-when-controller-has-resumed-from-background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIViewController *galleryViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
    [galleryViewController doSomething];
}
```

Edit: This is just an example of how you will get a reference to your GalleryViewController, if it is your rootViewController. If you are within NavigationController or TabBarController, you then need to first get a reference to your navigationController or tabBarController and then cascade it's viewControllers.

If you have a complex VC structure, it is probably easier to subscribe to notifications as Wain points out. The credit should go to his faster response.

Comment: foreground, not background

Comment: of course, must have been blind. edited the answer. thanks.

Comment: could you add a short explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the root view controller from the `window` in the app delegate and then cast or navigate the the controller you want (if it's in a navigation controller).

You don't need to add this relationship / knowledge to the app delegate though as the controller can add itself as an observer of the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification.

Comment: +1: `You don't need to add this relationship / knowledge to the app delegate`. If the app delegate doesn't need to know about it, then it shouldn't know about. Just add observer for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` as suggested into your `GalleryViewController` class.